# Удалить строки, содержащие символы

Tags: php

Есть txt файлы разного объема.

Нужно удалить строки, содержащие значения **'**, **%**, **$**, **@**.

В файле слова, каждое слово с новой строки.

Необходимо именно удалить всю строку, если есть хоть одно значение.

Comment: вы что-то уже сделали?

Comment: @allanklinton Приведите пример строки.

Comment: keud orfd
signs %26 loves
love's and film
prosdfsd sdf
test

Comment: @allanklinton Оформил, как ответ и сделал оптимизацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если построчно, то

```
preg_match('/[%$@]+/', 'hello %world');
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/oq1vYv)

#### UPDATE

Оптимизация:

```
$lines = [
    'keud orfd',
    'signs %26 loves'
];

$callback = function($line){
    return strpbrk($line, '%$@') === false;
};

var_dump(array_filter($lines, $callback));
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/yFieEJ)

**P.S.** Строковые функции быстрее, чем RegEx-ы.

Comment: > P.S. Строковые функции быстрее, чем RegEx-ы.

Ага. На целую одну седьмую.

https://gist.github.com/etki/fabab58af38402988886#file-sample-output

Comment: @Etki Доверился "инстинктам". Вы правы, выходит, что экономия на спичках. Хотя:

[regexpClosureAlgorithm](http://3v4l.org/I5X5l/perf#tabs)

[stringClosureAlgorithm](http://3v4l.org/QYcLh/perf#tabs)

Answer (score 0):

1. Открыть исходный файл для чтения.
2. Создать файл для результатов.
3. Прочитать одну строчку из 1 файла.
4. Если строчка вам подходит => записать во второй файл.
5. Если конец первого файла => "умереть", иначе вернуться к шагу 3.